# i need to start TCP Server and create multiple user to connect. i am facing issue i don't know how to create and write program?

Tags: java, spring

Kindly find in the details of assignment:

1. Start a TCP Server.
2. Start multiple clients to connect to the server.
3. On connect :
   Server gives each connection a random unique name
   Server starts sending PING messages to client as : “PING client abc123 at time hhmmss” every 5 seconds.
   Client receives the PING messages and prints them to console.
4. On connect :
   Client starts sending “Time request” messages every 10 seconds
   Server gets the message and responds : “Client abc123, the time is hhmmss”
   Client gets the time messages and prints them to console.

Things to note :
Use plain sockets (not NIO)
Make sure that the socket handling code is reusable
Make sure that the time request reads and writes are asynchronous.
Ensure that ping and all other reads and writes are also asynchronous
Ensure that ping and time response messages do not intersperse or corrupt each other

Comment: That's a pretty big task if you don't know how to program. You might think about changing to a beginner class. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We are not here to write a program for you, but here is some stuff you can use to solve most of the problems in your project.

First off you are using TCP in Java so you will be using the following objects:
`Socket` - Client connection
`ServerSocket` - Server host
There is documentation on how to use these [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Server side, you want multiple connections and you will want the rest of the program to run.  This means multitasking.  The ServerSocket should run on a separate thread.  Then it should be put in a `do-while` loop to `accept()` connections.  The server will then wait there until a client socket connects.  When a connection is made you will need to create a new thread to let the ServerSocket accept more clients.  Make sure when multi threading to use synchronized methods.

Create ServerSocket like this: `new ServerSocket(port);` This will open server on `int` port.

---

On the client side we will also use multithreading. The Socket will need to be on a seprate thread and to create a Socket to connect to an ip and port do the following: `new Socket(ip, port)` (ip is a String)

Once connected both the server and client will need to communicate. An easy way to do this is to send a message back and forth.  You can't just not send because the server or client will pause and wait on receive and not be able to send. I will get to this issue in a minute.

One way to send would be to use a `PrintWriter`. Create a new `PrintWriter` with the Socket output stream. From here you can send by printing line with `PrintWriter`.
Make sure you flush or `autoFlush` your `PrintWriter` or else it will keep sending the same message over and over.
You can then receive a message by using `BufferedReader` by creating a new `InputStreamReader` from the socket input stream. Doing this you can use `readLine()`. Remember this will pause until something is received.

Doing this on both the server and client you can send back and forth. Once at this point you could easily do the rest of your requested assignment.

---

As I mentioned earlier, this method will result in the server and clients sending and receiving over and over even if the message is empty.  Doing the following can prevent this and use less cpu and bandwidth as it will only send when it has a message to send:
[image]

(I created this diagram for a forum post for a project update I have created once)

The green lines represent received data going somewhere and the red represent data from the program going to the sender thread to be sent.
Notice on this diagram that there is a thread for receiving and sending.  This allows one to send messages while the other receives, so the sender won't pause if the receiver does pause to wait to receive a message.

---

Other good resources:

- [Simple Chat Program](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html)
- [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)